# angular using variables in ng-class / ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Disclaimer I am real new to angular and coding. I am trying to make a function that displays a certain amount of stars with each question.

everything works fine until I try to loop through a list of stars.

```
               <span  ng-repeat="a in range(7) track by $index">
                    <span  class="glyphicons glyphicons-star f18"
                            ng-class="rating[question.survey] >= {{$index + 1}} ? 'orange' : 'gray'"
                            ng-click="rating[question.survey] = {{$index + 1}}; setSurveyRating(rating); test();">
                    </span>
                </span>
```

If I go through and write out each span with an actual integer in place of `{{$index + 1}}` the code works fine. Any illumination on what is going on here?

Comment: Don't put the curly brackets there. There is no interpolation needed

Comment: Oh dude. Thanks. that makes total sense.